# Does $\xi$ invariance in $R_\xi$ gauges imply gauge invariance?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, gauge

Often in QFT calculations, a $R_\xi$ gauge fixing term
$$
\mathcal{L}_{GF} = \frac{1}{2\xi}(\partial_\mu A^\mu)
$$
is used, with $\xi$ left arbitrary. Any gauge invariant quantity must then be $\xi$ invariant. My question is: does any kind of converse exist - are all $\xi$ invariant quantities gauge invariant?
Or are there examples of a quantities that look gauge invariant in $R_\xi$ gauges (i.e. is independent of $\xi$) but are not actually gauge independent?

Comment: What forbids you to consider a gauge-dependent quantity that doesn't depend on $\xi$?

Answer (score 0):

The gauge fixing term you are referring to is equivalent to imposing an equivalence relation of the form$$A_\mu(x)\sim A'_\mu(x)\iff A'_\mu(x)=A_\mu(x)+\partial_\mu\phi(x)$$and then choosing a representative, i.e., selecting some $A_\mu(x)\in[A'_\mu(x)]_\sim$ to represent the space of all gauge fields under this equivalence relation. This ensures that your theory describes and and only one, unique $A_\mu(x)$. The $\xi$ quantity you refer to comes from the choice of representative. Arbitrary $\xi$ invariance does not necessarily imply gauge invariance, but when you choose a representative of the form you outlined, any gauge invariance quantity will necessarily be $\xi$ invariant.